# Выборка данных из SQL с помощью Python по дате

Tags: python, sql-server

Я совсем зелен в теме, у получилось выбирать нужные данные из таблицы SQL по дате. Но мне нужно получать данные каждый день, поэтому вручную менять дату каждый день неуддобном.

Есть таблица со сделками, у каждой сделки есть дата сделки. Для получения сделок пишу запрос:

```
"""select Securities_SecFullName, sell, SUM(qty)
    from Trades 
    WHERE Securities_SecFullName in ('П') and TradeDate = '06.07.2022  0:00:00' and ClassCode = 'T'
    and (Account = 'S' or ClientCode = 'U' or ClientCode = 'B')
    group by Securities_SecFullName, sell"""
```

Для сортировки по дате в данный момент использую WHERE и вручную пишу дату. В таблице дата сделки представлена в виде: '06.07.2022  0:00:00'

Подскажите, как использовать CURDATE() или что-то другое, чтобы запрос брал сразу текущую дату. Я испробовал несколько вариантов, которые нашел, но все они выдавали ошибки. Надеюсь я выразился более менее понятно. Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Comment: Выбрать надо по какой дате? сегодняшней? TradeDate - какой точно тип данных у поля?

Comment: Дата нужна сегодняшняя. Тип данных - datetime

Comment: Ну тады `.. AND CAST(TradeDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ..`...

Comment: Спасибо, что бы я без вас делал) Удивительно, но нигде не нашел ответа на такой вопрос, оказалось все просто.